# function nil.id/0 is undefined - Elixir, Phoenix

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I can't figure out how to do the check correctly to hide the actions from the user

```elixir
<%= if @current_user.id == @post.user_id do %>
  <span>
    <%= link "Edit", to: Routes.post_path(@conn, :edit, @post) %>
  </span>
  <span>
    <%= link "Delete", to: Routes.post_path(@conn, :delete, @post), method: :delete, data: [confirm: "Are you sure"] %>
  </span>
<% end %>
```

When the user is not logged in, this error appears:

> UndefinedFunctionError at GET `/posts/1` function `nil.id/0` is undefined

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In this case, your `@current_user` is `nil`, so Elixir tries to run `nil.id` which fails.

You could probably solve your issue by checking for `nil` first:

```elixir
<%= if @current_user && @current_user.id == @post.user_id do %>
```

The error message is a bit confusing because `nil` is also an atom, and the `a.b` syntax has two uses in Elixir:

- accessing an atom key `:b` on a map/struct `a` (what you are trying to do)
- calling the `a.b()` function, with `a` being a module atom

`nil` also being an atom, it gets interpreted as `nil.id()`, but the `nil.id/0` function doesn't exist since `nil` is not an actual module.

Comment: @Aleksandr please mark the answer as correct by pressing the huge green checkmark on the left-top of the answer.